# Css media queries - conflict with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have a div with `display:none` (mobile first approach):

```
  #my_div {
     display: none;
     color: red;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
  }
```

I use some media queries (after in the css) to display this div with some padding and font-size:

```
 /* Between 600px and 649px */
 @media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 649px) {
    #my_div {
       display: inline-block;
       padding-top: 26px;
       padding-left: 15px;
       font-size: 18px;
    }
 }

 /* Between 650px and 699px */
 @media (min-width:650px) and (max-width:699px) {
   #my_div {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 24px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
   }
}​

/* Between 700px and 914px */
@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 914px) {
   #my_div {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 22px;
      padding-left: 35px;
      font-size: 22px;
   }
}
```

All works well until 699px. The third media query is not applied and the div isn't displayed.

If I use the following media queries, the div is displayed, but `@media (min-width: 700px)` is not applied. The `@media (min-width:650px)` is applied:

```
 @media (min-width: 600px) {
    #my_div {
       display: inline-block;
       padding-top: 26px;
       padding-left: 15px;
       font-size: 18px;
    }
 }

 @media (min-width:650px) {
   #my_div {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 24px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
   }
}​

@media (min-width: 700px) {
   #my_div {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 22px;
      padding-left: 35px;
      font-size: 22px;
   }
}
```

By using the chrome inspector I can see that over 700px it's applied the rule:

```
  #my_div {
     display: none;
     ...
  }
```

**EDIT**

I have added one more media query

```
 #my_div {
     display: none;
     color: red;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
  }

 @media (min-width: 600px) {
    #my_div {
       display: inline-block;
       padding-top: 26px;
       padding-left: 15px;
       font-size: 18px;
    }
 }

 @media (min-width:650px) {
   #my_div {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 24px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
   }
}​

@media (min-width: 768px) {
   #my_div {
      display: none; /* it doesn't work, also with !important */
   }
}

@media (min-width: 915px) {
   #my_div {
     display: inline-block;
     padding-top: 22px;
     padding-left: 35px;
     font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

The only rule that is not applied is `@media (min-width: 768px)`.

In my CSS, there aren't other rules that affect the display of `my_div` div. I'm using Bootstrap 3.

**EDIT 2**

I added the Bootstrap `hidden-sm` class to the div `my_div`:

```
 <div id="my_div" class="hidden-sm"><strong>My slogan</strong></div>
```

In this way the div isn't displayed between 768px and 991px, but I would to display it again from 915px.

**SOLUTION**

I updated the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ero1k9n3/6/) by AngelosCharalis and, by copying and paste my code, I found an invisible dot character. Now it works.

Comment: The `max-width` queries are not needed, use only `min-width` to do what you want. Moving your code to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ero1k9n3/1/), it seems to work well for me. I just removed the `max-width` queries, are you certain that no other part of your code messes up this styling?

Comment: @AngelosChalaris: in your JSFiddle it seems the div is always displayed. By using only `min-width` the `@media (min-width: 700px)` is not applied anyway

Comment: it is not always displayed, if you shrink the results area it eventually disappears. And over 700px it does show... - Added a `color:blue` to over 700px to make it clear: https://jsfiddle.net/ero1k9n3/2/

Comment: Again, colored to showcase it: https://jsfiddle.net/ero1k9n3/3/ It all works correctly!

Comment: @AngelosChalaris: yes. The jsfiddle example works, I changed the background on all media queries, but on my code the issue remains. I'll try other inspectors.

Answer (score -1):

First you must start from the highest pixel.

```
@media (max-width: 914px) {
    #myId {

    }
}
@media (max-width: 699px) {
    #myId {

    }
}
@media (max-width: 649px) {
    #myId {

    }
}
@media (max-width: 599px) {
    #myId {

    }
}
```